# Request builder call not returning when using ssl(https)

Tags: gwt, ssl, https, gwt-rpc

I am using GWT. Currently using gwt-rpc to for login authentication. For only login purpose i want to use ssl(https) and so instead of using gwt-rpc i am trying Request Builder and calling a servlet with https.
When in Servlet URL i use protocol as http the request builder works perfectly and response returns to client side(onResponseReceived ). but when i use https in the servlet url then the servlet is gettting called but the response is not returning to the onResponseReceived method of request builder.

my url with http looks like : http://localhost:8888/myproject/myservlet
and with https it looks like :https://localhost/myproject/myservlet

Please give any suggestion or is there any other way to do it.and also is it possible to use ssl over gwt-rpc.

Answer (score 1):

[Browser Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) is blocking your requests.

Your page was requested over http, but you are now making an ajax call over https. This is a violation of same origin policy.

To get around, you should serve your original html/servlet over https. This does have a performance cost, but it is the only way to build a secure website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familliar with GWT and Request Builder, but whenever I have had problems with HTTPS connections from my code it has come down to certificates and having the right certificate installed in the client or telling the client code where to find the certificate in order to encode the call.

That would be the first avenue I would want to explore in your situation.