# Gwt How to call servlet/rpc through https from page originated from http

Tags: gwt, ssl, https, gwt-rpc

is there  any way to call servlet or make a gwt-rpc call from gwt client and get back the response. Or to call RPC over https only for login purpose.
Please suggest any method or workaround to implement the above task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [I mentioned in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673685/request-builder-call-not-returning-when-using-sslhttps/2674379#2674379), its a violation of same origin policy. You can't do it.

You can POST (using a FormPanel) to a https website, but you can't read the data back. Even such an approach is unsecure, because someone can easily spoof the post url.

The only way to stay secure is to serve all content via https.